# How to shorten a URL in objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4

I found several examples for shortening an `URL`. But none of them did not work for me. If anyone have working example, please share.
What I have tried,

```
 NSString *apiEndpoint = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://tinyurl.com/api-create.php?url=%@",strUrl];
NSString *shortURL = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:apiEndpoint]
                                              encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding
                                                 error:nil];
NSLog(@"Long: %@ - Short: %@",strUrl,shortURL);

NSString *shortenedURL = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://api.bit.ly/v3/shorten?login=%@&apikey=%@&longUrl=%@&format=txt", @"smartsanja@gmail.com", @"R_2db6e96aad348b8c993acf6ba80884c4", strUrl]] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

NSLog(@"Shoted url %@", [shortenedURL JSONValue]);
```

Comment: also first paste this line above ur code strUrl = [strUrl stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just try bellow code for short url..

1.try first this..

```
NSString *urlstr = yourURL ;///here put your URL in string
[urlstr retain];
NSString *apiEndpoint = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://ggl-shortener.appspot.com/?url=%@",urlstr];
[apiEndpoint retain];

NSLog(@"\n\n APIEndPoint : %@",apiEndpoint);
NSString *shortURL = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:apiEndpoint]
                                              encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding
                                                 error:nil];
shortURL = [shortURL stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"{\"short_url\":\"" withString:@""];
shortURL = [shortURL stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\",\"added_to_history\":false}" withString:@""];
[shortURL retain];
NSLog(@"Long: %@ - Short: %@",urlstr,shortURL);
```

2.second way is bellow

```
NSString *urlstr =[yourURL stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];///your url string 
            [urlstr retain];
            NSString *apiEndpoint = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://tinyurl.com/api-create.php?url=%@",urlstr];
            [apiEndpoint retain];

            NSLog(@"\n\n APIEndPoint : %@",apiEndpoint);
            NSString *shortURL = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:apiEndpoint]
                                                          encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding
                                                             error:nil];
[shortURL retain];
    NSLog(@"Long: %@ - Short: %@",urlstr,shortURL);
```

hope this help you...

:)

Comment: Thanks bro. But I still get NULL for short url :(   Long: http://sandbox.saberion.com/beauty-morph/20120917-16380045-8658069 - Short: (null) ................ do you have any idea whats wrong???

Comment: hi mate just try my second option i know you use this tinyurl but try my code one time.. hope this work fine... :)

Answer (score 1):

[This NSURL category of mine](https://github.com/H2CO3/Shortener/blob/master/NSURL+Shortener.m) returns directly a shortened NSURL.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one, its working fine to me.

```
NSString *apiEndpoint = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://tinyurl.com/api-create.php?url=%@",shareUrlString]; // The shareUrlString is NSString, which having URl

shortenUrl = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:apiEndpoint] encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:nil]; //ShortenUrl is NSString
```